# Switch DB-Connection for one TestCase in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oracle, unit-testing

I try to switch the db connection for one testcase within the setup and teardown.
But somehow the tests return me this message:

```
RuntimeError: executing in another thread
```

And thats the testcase code:

```
def setup
  Example.establish_connection(ActiveRecord::Base.configurations['oracle'])
end

def teardown
  Example.establish_connection(Rails.env)
end
```

The test db is sqlite and db I try to use for the testcase is oracle because of a PLSQL function.

Comment: Do you use any test support library which threads/forks in order to improve performance?

Comment: I use guard to trigger the test automatically but without spork.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a potential race condition to me. The setup may not complete if the `'oracle'` `ActiveRecord` connection already exists in another thread.

Have you tried explicitly closing the `'oracle'` connection at the start of your `teardown` method?